# Error: Build failed when dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a web API. Every time I run dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration I get build failed error. I was following the youtube tutorial to build a dashboard using ASP.NET and Angular and Postgresql as databases. I tried looking up the docs, went through past StackOverflow queries and everything I could do still couldn't solve this issue. I am stuck in my project for 5 days just because of this issue.
[image]

.NET SDK 5.0

Advantage.API.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>User-Secret-Id</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.7">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

ApiContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Advantage.API.Demo.Models
{
    public class ApiContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApiContext(DbContextOptions<ApiContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Advantage.API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Advantage.API.Models;


namespace Advantage.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private string _connectionString = null;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            _connectionString = Configuration["secretConnectionString"];
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Advantage.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApiContext>(opt=>opt.UseNpgsql(_connectionString));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Advantage.API v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error is due to your program is unable to compile, instead of the migration issue. Please try and check your build error and post it here.

Comment: Hi j.f, I have posted the output screen from VScode, is that sth you are looking for?

Comment: The Compiler is unable to find Advantage.API project. Please ensure this project is added to the solution.

Comment: You can only run EF tools on a project that compiles. Make your project compile by fixing all the build errors. Comment out code if you have to...

Answer (score 0):

Opening the VSCode from terminal helped me to detect the errors. Eliminated those error and build succeded.